# c++ workaround: `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘C*&’ from expression of type ‘B*’

Tags: c++, templates

Lately I've found this error for the first time: `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘C*&’ from expression of type ‘B*’`. The error came up when porting code from `gcc 4.9` to `gcc 6`. Below I pasted a minimal example of the code.

```
class A {
public:
    A() : a(1) {};
    virtual ~A() {};
    int a;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : val(2) {};
    int val;
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C() : val(3) {};
    float val;
};

int alloc_b(B*& entry) {
    try {
        entry = new B;
    } catch(...) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int alloc_c(C*& entry) {
    try {
        entry = new C;
    } catch(...) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
int whatever(const bool isB) {
    T* entry = NULL;
    if(isB) {
        alloc_b(entry);
    } else {
        alloc_c(entry);
    }

    std::cout << entry->val << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int rv;
    B* ptrB;
    C* ptrC;

    whatever<B>(true);
    whatever<C>(false);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the error appears because when compiling the method `whatever` with `isB = true` it is also trying to compile also the `alloc_c()` call, so it checks that `T = B` and can't find any `alloc_c(B*& entry)` method, so it fails. And the other way `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘B*&’ from expression of type ‘C*’` when the method `whatever` is called with type `C` and `isB = false`.

I was just wondering what's the cleanest way to get around this problem. The only solution I've found was creating a method template `alloc` with some specializations:

```
template<typename T>
int alloc(T*& entry) {
    static_assert((std::is_same<decltype(entry), B>::value ||
                    std::is_same<decltype(entry), C>::value),
                    "Class must be A or B");
}

template<>
int alloc(B*& entry) {
    return alloc_b(entry);
}

template<>
int alloc(C*& entry) {
    return alloc_c(entry);
}
```

And then from inside the `whatever` function, I'd call that alloc instead of the other allocs.

```
template<typename T>
int whatever(const bool isB) {
    T* entry = NULL;
    alloc(entry);

    std::cout << entry->val << "\n";
}
```

But I'm sure there has to be a cleaner way to get around this error.

Comment: FWIW `template<typename T>
int alloc(T*& entry)` can be written as `template<typename T>
int alloc(T*& entry) = delete;` as well.  You won't get as nice of an error message but you won't have to type as much.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that the error appears **because when compiling the method whatever with isB = true it is also trying to compile also the alloc_c() call**, so it checks that T = B and can't find any alloc_c(B*& entry) method, so it fails.

You can prevent that from happening by giving this compile-time evaluated `isB` instead:

```
template<typename T, bool isB>
int whatever();
```

Now, using [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) will give you the desired feature without hurting your code too much:

```
template<typename T, bool isB>
int whatever() {
    T* entry = NULL;
    if constexpr (isB) {
        alloc_b(entry);
    } else {
        alloc_c(entry);
    }

    std::cout << entry->val << "\n";
}

whatever<B, true>();
whatever<C, false>();
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FA73ek9HA2arvz3z)

**EDIT**

Without `if constexpr`, SFINAE still works - you'll just have to do more typing:

```
template<typename T, bool isB>
typename std::enable_if<isB, int>::type whatever() {
    T* entry = NULL;
    alloc_b(entry);

    std::cout << entry->val << "\n";
}

template<typename T, bool isB>
typename std::enable_if<!isB, int>::type whatever() {
    T* entry = NULL;
    alloc_c(entry);

    std::cout << entry->val << "\n";
}
```

[Tested with gcc 6.1.0.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pa1RYxdcWdCsQpK2)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The only problem is that whenever I try to compile I get: `expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’`, as if `constexpr` was not recognized. I made sure I'm compiling with `gcc 6` (in case C++17 is not compatible with my other cpp compilers), but I get the same error anyways.